# How to oracle partition by date range Unix Timestamp

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning, oracle19c

I have below table in oracle, I want Partition Range by Date  in Oracle monthly on `MyTimestamp` column(Data type is number). Can I partition with this column or do I need another column? If I need a new column, what is the data type of the new column and how do I partition with the new column(convert `MyTimestamp` to new data type and partition )?

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id  | MyTimestamp  |    Name        | etc ...    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 |  1657640396  |    John        |  ...    
|   1 |  1657638832  |    Tom         |  ...    
|   2 |  1657640265  |    Tom         |  ...    
|   3 |  1657640292  |    John        |  ...    
|   4 |  1657640005  |    Jack        |  ...    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a virtual column and define partition key on that:

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
   id NUMBER,
   MyTimestamp NUMBER
   Name VARCHAR2(100), 
   etc...
   PARTITION_KEY TIMESTAMP(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( 
      CAST(TRUNC(TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + MyTimestamp * INTERVAL '1' SECOND) AS TIMESTAMP(0)) 
   ) VIRTUAL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (PARTITION_KEY)
INTERVAL (INTERVAL '1' MONTH)
(  
  PARTITION P_INITIAL VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00') 
);
```

You could also use `MyTimestamp` directly, however 2'635'200 (i.e. 30.5 days) seconds is **just roughly** a month

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
   id NUMBER,
   MyTimestamp NUMBER
   Name VARCHAR2(100), 
   etc...
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (MyTimestamp)
INTERVAL (2635200)
(  
  PARTITION P_INITIAL VALUES LESS THAN (1640991600) 
);
```

Comment: Thanks I test That,please help me for index this table in this question `https://stackoverflow.com/q/73018170/12780274`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to PARTITION by DATE, you need a date column. Below is an example with some dummy data.

When new PARTITIONs are automatically added they will have system GENERATED names. I have code to RENAME them to something meaningful  if you like.

In addition, you will probably want to implement a RETENTION period for the PARTITION, how long to keep them around. I also implemented that too.

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (     
 seq_num NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
   dt   DATE
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (dt)
INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH'))
(
   PARTITION OLD_DATA values LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2022-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
);
/

INSERT into t2 (dt)
with dt (dt, interv) as (
select date '2022-01-01', numtodsinterval(1,'DAY') from dual
union all
select dt.dt + interv, interv from dt
where dt.dt + interv < date '2022-07-31')
select dt from dt;
/

By timestamp 

CREATE TABLE t3 (
seq_num NUMBER  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
dt TIMESTAMP)
  PARTITION BY RANGE (dt) 
  INTERVAL ( NUMTODSINTERVAL (1, 'MONTH') ) ( 
    PARTITION OLD_DATA VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP '2022-01-01 00:00:00.000000')
  );
/

INSERT into t3 (dt)
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-01-01 00:00:00'
         + (LEVEL - 1) * INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
         + MOD(LEVEL - 1, 10) * INTERVAL '0.1' SECOND
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY
       TIMESTAMP '2022-01-01 00:00:00'
         + (LEVEL - 1) * INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
         + MOD(LEVEL - 1, 10) * INTERVAL '0.1' SECOND < DATE '2022-01-15';
/
```

Comment: Thanks. T2 partition with Date Type and T3 partition with Timestamp type?

Comment: Yes, look at dt in both tables. In t2 it's a date and t3 it's a timestamp. I also gave you a way to generate sample data so the PARTITION can be created and you can see what's going on. If I answered your question please upvote my answer. In addition, I have other code to RENAME PARTITIONs and to deal with RETENTION

Comment: time stamp is faster or Date data type?

Comment: Faster? What are you referring too? You will need to decide between global or local indexes if they are needed and test your queries. Also decide whether you need to keep dates or timestamps. I think performance should be equivalent but you should do the correct amount of testing and see what works best for you

Comment: Thanks, please help me for index this table in this question `https://stackoverflow.com/q/73018170/12780274`