# global or local indexes on column with duplicate value in Oracle 19C?

Tags: database-partitioning, oracle19c, database-indexes

I have below table on Oracle19c(I am an oracle newbie). 4 million rows are inserted into the table daily and for now this table have 40 column and 240 million rows.

I usually search the table with user_id and MyTimestamp columns filter query and it takes 10 minutes to return the answer.

Example:
`select * from table where user_id=123581  and MyTimestamp between 1657640396 and 1657777396` 
Note: Duplicate values are stored in the `user_id` and `MyTimestamp` columns.

I want partition monthly on `MyTimestamp`   and index on `user_id` but which global or local indexes is suitable for indexing and how do I do it?

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id  | MyTimestamp  |    Name        | user_id   ...    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 |  1657640396  |    John        | 123581         ...    
|   1 |  1657638832  |    Tom         | 168525         ...    
|   2 |  1657640265  |    Tom         | 168525         ...    
|   3 |  1657640292  |    John        | 123581         ...    
|   4 |  1657640005  |    Jack        | 896545         ...    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the majority of your queries contain the partition key, then better create `LOCAL` indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name  ON table_name (MyTimestamp, user_id) LOCAL;
```

Local indexes are smaller (i.e. the index partition) and thus faster and you don't have to rebuild the index when you drop an outdated partition.

Comment: `user_id` column data type is faster if integer or varchar2?

Comment: Should make no difference at all.